# Mount external SD folder to /data/user

Tags: root-access, external-sd, mount

I'm trying to free up some space and install large games on my rooted Samsung Galaxy S2 with an external SD card. The app I've been using is [*FolderMount*](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devasque.fmount), which mounts any folder in a different location. Using this app, I've successfully mounted `/storage/extSdCard/Android/obb/com.*.appname` to `/storage/sdcard0/Android/obb/com.*.appname` for a number of apps. I've also sucessfully mounted `/storage/extSdCard/data/com.*.app` to `/data/data/com.*.app`. This effectively means anything that tries to access these locations on my internal storage actually accesses the external location, thinking it's on the internal storage (basically the same effect as symlinking), as far as I understand the process.

However, I'm now looking at an app which stores large amounts of data in `/data/user/0/com.*.theapp` and *FolderMount* fails to access the user profile: When I navigate to `/data/user/` in *FolderMount*, it shows the folder as empty, even though it contains the folder `0/` when I navigate to it using *RootBrowser*. Since *FolderMount* uses root permissions, this shouldn't be an issue, but just to be sure, I edited the `0/` folder's permissions to `0777` and it didn't help.

So now my question is, **how do I mount an external location to my `/data/user/0/` folder**?

Is there a profound reason *FolderMount* can't access my user profile folder? Can I achieve the same result with a different app? I have *Link2SD*, but the free version doesn't link app data and I don't want to buy an app to do something I can perfectly do for free with a different app...

Comment: New information: I discovered `/data/user/0/` is somehow linked to `/data/data`, but I neither know why nor how nor which way. Is there a way to find out?